# Connection error with android application

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, nullpointerexception

Hello in first place thanks to everyone for the help,

I have a problem with my android application, really am new to all this,
Reproduce this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Do not put all the code here, because the truth is not that part may be failing, to download the complete code can be downloaded here: http://www.mediafire.com/download/77zlcvvhre40303/androidhive.rar

The log file gives these errors:

> 11-14 20:48:01.828: E/Buffer Error(1079): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.828: E/JSON Parser(1079): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.828: D/AndroidRuntime(1079): Shutting down VM
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.828: W/dalvikvm(1079): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at com.example.androidhive.RegisterActivity$1.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:59)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
>
> 11-14 20:48:01.836: E/AndroidRuntime(1079):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 11-14 20:50:18.675: I/Process(1079): Sending signal. PID: 1079 SIG: 9

And the console say this

> [2014-11-16 08:21:51 - ddms] Can't bind to local 8700 for debugger

RegisterActivity:

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.androidhive.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.example.androidhive.library.UserFunctions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
Button btnRegister;
Button btnLinkToLogin;
EditText inputFullName;
EditText inputEmail;
EditText inputPassword;
TextView registerErrorMsg;
 
// JSON Response node names
private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.register);

    // Importing all assets like buttons, text fields
    inputFullName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerName);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerEmail);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);
     
    // Register Button Click event
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);
             
            // check for login response
            try {
                if (json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null) {
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        // user successfully registred
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");
                         
                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));                       
                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);
                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);
                        // Close Registration Screen
                        finish();
                    }else{
                        // Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            // Close Registration View
            finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: what are you actually doing i dont get you..Sir

Comment: What is at RegisterActivity.java:59 line 59? Some Code of that portion plz.